# Using Rcpp's runif() function within in RcppArmadillo's sample() function

Tags: rcpp

I have an Rcpp script where I do the following:

```
double m = runif(1); // generate a random number uniformly between 0 and 1.
```

I then pass m to sample() as follows:

```
IntegerVector ind = RcppArmadillo::sample<IntegerVector>(perms, ceil(num_specs * m), false); // int perms, num_specs.
```

The above line results in an error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'NumericVector' (aka 'Vector<14>') to 'double'
```

Unless my thinking (or declarations) is flawed, runif(1) is a scalar (double) not a vector (NumericVector).

The above works fine when I declare:

```
double m = 0;
```

Could someone point out how to get around the issue with runif()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `RcppArmadilloExtensions/` directory in the RcppArmadillo header directory -- there is an entire `sample()` example set up for RcppArmadillo.

And there are

- [a first Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-the-Rcpp-based-sample-implementation/)
- [a second Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/an-example-of-using-Rcpp-sample/)

with an examples for sampling using it.

Otherwise your problem may be one of confusing the *scalar* `R::runif()` (using the C API of R) with the *vectorised* `Rcpp::runif()` returning a vector.  If you are more explicit about which one  you use (i.e. explicit namespacing with `::`) your code may still work.